# PHP - Argument 1 passed to foo must be an instance of Bar, string given - how to call ctor automatically

Tags: php, casting

I have this code:

```
class Bar {
   public function __construct($s){
   }

   public function __toString(){
    return "something";
   }
}

function foo(Bar $b){

}

foo("xx");
```

Is there any possibility to call `Bar` ctor implicitly, eg. cast "string" to `Bar` without explicitely calling `new Bar("xx")`? I can use `$b` instance in foo as string, because of `__toString` method. I just need some processing done before and dont want to write everywhere `new Bar`.

Comment: The purpose of the type hint is precisely to avoid that. If you prefer loosely typed function calls just omit it and have `function foo($b){}`.

Comment: A type hint ensures that the data you *get* is of the type you expect. If you want your function to cast *any* data to the type you desire, do `$b = new Bar($b)` inside your own code.